# Scope of counters in paracol environment

Tags: counters, paracol, scoping

I am trying to use longtables in MDPI article template but their numbering is incorrect (it always starts from 1).

What have I tried so far?

Below is minimal working example. I've stripped the template to bare minimum and added only the things that are necessary.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{paracol}
\title{Tables}

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\switchcolumn
\newcounter{yolo}
\newpage
\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{center}
        \caption{Your first table.}
        \begin{tabular}{l|c|r} % <-- Alignments: 1st column left, 2nd middle and 3rd right, with vertical lines in between
            \textbf{Value 1} & \textbf{Value 2} & \textbf{Value 3}\\
            \hline
            a & b & c\\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
\setcounter{yolo}{\thetable}
\theyolo
\end{paracol}


\theyolo
\setcounter{table}{\theyolo}
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|}
    \caption{A sample long table.} \\

    \hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Third column}} \\ \hline 
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{3}{c}%
    {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
    \hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Third column}} \\ \hline 
    \endhead

    \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
    \endfoot

    \endlastfoot

    1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\switchcolumn 

\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{center}
        \caption{Your first table.}
        \begin{tabular}{l|c|r} % <-- Alignments: 1st column left, 2nd middle and 3rd right, with vertical lines in between
            \textbf{Value 1} & \textbf{Value 2} & \textbf{Value 3}\\
            \hline
            a & b & c\\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
\setcounter{yolo}{\thetable}
\theyolo
\end{paracol}
\small
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.2mm}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\theyolo
\setcounter{table}{\theyolo}
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|}
    \caption{A sample long table.}\\
    \hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Third column}} \\ \hline 
    \endfirsthead

    \multicolumn{3}{c}%
    {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
    \hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Third column}} \\ \hline 
    \endhead

    \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
    \endfoot

    \endlastfoot

    1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

I've tried to use a counter (named yolo in the example above) that keeps value of tables. Its value is then used to set a counter of longtables. The problem is that for some reason yolo counter seems to have an old value outside of `paracol` environment.

To better summarize the problem:
[image]

The last number (underlined in red) suppose to be 3, but it is stuck with an old value.

Comment: I don't think anyone can properly help you with at least a link to the template. Also, even if you cannot post a minimal working example, make sure to remove all parts of the code that are not directly related to your issue. Actually, what do you mean by "is marked as spam"? And lastly, what exactly is your problem with numbering starting at 1, sounds pretty normal to me.

Comment: Please make sure your example is self contained. We do not have access to `Definitions/mdpi` for example. I would not expect `\setcounter{yolo}{\thetable}` to work in general as `\thetable` does not need to be an integer. Probablly better with `\value{table}`.

Comment: @MarkusG. I've edited the question and removed all unnecessary elements from the snippet as you said. By "marked as spam" I mean exactly that. I could not have posted a question because each time I pressed the "post question" button I've received an error with "This looks like spam.".

Comment: What's a source for `mdpi.cls`?

Comment: @egreg I've changed the example so it doesn't need mdpi classes anymore.

Comment: I am still not sure what you are trying to achieve here. The `table` counter works like it should, so I do not understand the need of the addtional counter. Also, you never add any increments to the counter (such as with `\stepcounter{}`) so, obviously it will not change its value. Or maybe I just do not understand what you are doing. Can you explain what you are trying to do in more detail?

Comment: @MarkusG. Thanks for patience! I am trying to insert few longtables along regular tables into my document. The problem is that even though the caption prefixes for both environments are the same (that is "table"), the numberings for each elements are separate. The picture at the bottom of my post shows the result. I would like the tables and longtables to be numbered 1->2->3->4. Without additional counter they are numbered 1->1->2->2 with my custom "yolo" counter the numbering is better but still not correct (1->2->3->2).

Comment: I'm beginning to understand. I had a discussion about the differences in numbering of `tabulars` and `longtables` for another question. My guess is that the easiest solution for what you are trying to do is direct manipulation of the table counter, as in `\setcounter{table}{}` or incrementally by using `\stepcounter{table}` or something similar. There shouldn't be a need for a seperate counter.

Comment: @MarkusG. If outside of `paracol` environment counter for tables is separated from the counter within `paracol` environment how can I pass a number of tables between environments (outside and inside of `paracol` in this case) without an additional counter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone having a similar problem.

The answer is based on `paracol` package documentation available at:
https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/paracol/paracol.pdf
(page 10 - "Local and Global counters")

In order to set counters to be global one need to write: `\globalcounter{table}` in the preamble of document.

This way there is no need for any additional counter, tables and longtables are considered as the same type of elements.

Using the previous example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{paracol}

\globalcounter{table}
\title{Tables}

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\switchcolumn
%\newcounter{yolo}
\newpage
\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{center}
        \caption{Your first table.}
        \begin{tabular}{l|c|r} % <-- Alignments: 1st column left, 2nd middle and 3rd right, with vertical lines in between
            \textbf{Value 1} & \textbf{Value 2} & \textbf{Value 3}\\
            \hline
            a & b & c\\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
%\setcounter{yolo}{\thetable}
%\theyolo
\end{paracol}


%\theyolo
%\setcounter{table}{\theyolo}
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|}
    \caption{A sample long table.} \\

    \hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Third column}} \\ \hline 
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{3}{c}%
    {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
    \hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Third column}} \\ \hline 
    \endhead
    
    \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
    \endfoot
    
    \endlastfoot
    
    1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\switchcolumn 

\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{center}
        \caption{Your first table.}
        \begin{tabular}{l|c|r} % <-- Alignments: 1st column left, 2nd middle and 3rd right, with vertical lines in between
            \textbf{Value 1} & \textbf{Value 2} & \textbf{Value 3}\\
            \hline
            a & b & c\\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
%\setcounter{yolo}{\thetable}
%\theyolo
\end{paracol}
\small
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.2mm}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
%\theyolo
%\setcounter{table}{\theyolo}
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|}
    \caption{A sample long table.}\\
    \hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Third column}} \\ \hline 
    \endfirsthead
    
    \multicolumn{3}{c}%
    {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
    \hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Third column}} \\ \hline 
    \endhead
    
    \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
    \endfoot
    
    \endlastfoot
    
    1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```